# php registration form issue

Tags: php

I am new to php and am trying to register users code but it is not working properly. If I comment out the header('location:login.php'); then it saves the data in the database and if I uncomment this header('location:login.php'); then it does not save the data in the database and opens the login page.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>records...</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="registration.php" method="post">
            <table border="1" align="center" cellspacing="2">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="id"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>username</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>password</th>
                    <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>email</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>contact</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="contact"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center" style="color: red"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <?php
            error_reporting(0);

            if(isset($_REQUEST["submit"])){
                //header('location:login.php');

                require 'conn.php';
                $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
                $username=$_REQUEST['username'];
                $password=$_REQUEST['password'];
                $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
                $contact=$_REQUEST['contact'];
                $query="insert into dhr values('$id','$username','$password','$email','$contact')";

                $result=  mysql_query($query);
                if($result>0){
                    echo"insert successfully..";
                } else {
                    echo "not inserted".  mysql_error();
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please explain me your exact issue?

Comment: can you please specify the error or probelm?

Comment: ... Did you write this code? I very much doubt it, if you did, then please don't add code without knowing what it does, `header(location:...);` redirects the user, so of course if you un-comment it, it will redirect users, as it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
you not to be define id in this form.because ID should be autoincrement. then after you create a login page(login.php) then two fields username and password same as just like work on registration page. 


<html>
    <head>
        <title>records...</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <table border="1" align="center" cellspacing="2">

                <tr>
                    <th>username</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>password</th>
                    <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>email</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>contact</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="contact"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center" style="color: red"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <?php
           if(isset($_REQUEST["submit"])){
                require 'conn.php';
                $username=$_REQUEST['username'];
                $password=$_REQUEST['password'];
                $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
                $contact=$_REQUEST['contact'];
                $query="insert into dhr(username,password,email,contact)values('$id','$username','$password','$email','$contact')";

                $result=  mysql_query($query);
                if($result>0){
                   // echo"insert successfully..";
                      header('location:login.php');
                } else {
                    echo "not inserted".  mysql_error();
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are redirecting before saving values in databse. Use `header()` function after saving values in database. Do like this. here is your full correct code.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0); 
    if(isset($_REQUEST["submit"])){ 
        require 'conn.php';
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
        $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
        $password = $_REQUEST['password'];
        $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $contact = $_REQUEST['contact'];
        $query = "insert into dhr values('$id','$username','$password','$email','$contact')";               
        if(mysql_query($query)){
            //echo"insert successfully..";
            header('location:login.php');
        }else{
            echo "not inserted".  mysql_error();
        }   
    }   
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>records...</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="registration.php" method="post">
            <table border="1" align="center" cellspacing="2">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="id"></td>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <th>username</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>password</th>
                    <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>email</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>contact</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="contact"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center" style="color: red"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td>
                </tr>


            </table>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   [click here for more details about header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: Good answer. Please note that `mysql_query()` returns `true` or `false` for `INSERT` queries: "For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error. ". Suggested an edit. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: @Narxx, Yes you are absolutely right. We can also use `mysql_insert_id` — Get the ID generated in the last query, to know if the record inserted in database.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are just redirecting after checking `form` is posted or not

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["submit"])){


                header('location:login.php');// this will redirect you without executing your code below this Beacuse you have written it here
```

Just write it below the `insert query`
like

```
if($result>0){

               echo"insert successfully..";
                header('location:login.php');// if you want redirect from here
            }
```